# adding variables to Codeigniter calendar next/prev links

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a CI calendar showing on a page, with an array of data sent to populate each day, and that's working fine, however I seem to have run into a small problem that I can't quite wrap my head around.

I've only known CI for about 3 days (and OOP based PHP for 5 days!), so forgive me if this is something incredibly simple.

I need to get a variable ($pid) into my calendar's next/prev links. The $pid will define which property to get from the DB, and to display the properties rates for the selected month.

In my "MY_Calendar.php" file, I have the following:

```
var $CI;
var $lang;
var $local_time;
var $template       = '';
var $start_day      = 'sunday';
var $month_type     = 'long';
var $day_type       = 'abr';
var $show_next_prev = TRUE;
var $next_prev_url  = '/ci/index.php/rates/property/1/';
```

Where the /1/ is in the url, I need that to change to whatever the $pid is of the page that the calendar is on.

How can I get this variable into the class file?

I'm assuming it'd be a simple PHP concatenation to get the variable in the URL.

I tried calling the preferences via "$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);"

But the preferences didn't seem to come through (I had a array named $prefs on the same page)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: why are you using the $CI superobject? Are you working in a Codeigniter view, calling it from a model, right?

Comment: That's what was initially in the calendar.php file, which I then made into MY_calendar.php. I'm loading the library in a controller, and then outputting the result to a view. Is this how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already extended the CI_Calendar class, just add a new class property:

```
var $pid = 1;
```

If you pass in the config array, and you're calling the parent constructor, it should allow you to pass in / set the `$pid` variable.

Then you'd obviously remove that value from `$next_prev_url`.

Finally, you will override the function that outputs the next/prev buttons to concatenate the `$next_prev_url` with the correct `$pid`. You should set `$pid` to the current page, so teh previous will be -1 and next +1, ofcourse checking for the min and max page number to prevent those links from being shown if you get to the end.

Comment: Does this look right to you? $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

$data['cal'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $data['combined_array'], $prefs);  It doesn't seem to load the $prefs array, only loading the default config in the MY_calendar.php file